# Using a generic function in dplyr summarise_all

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use *summarise_all()* inside of a function to apply a generic function to all columns of a data frame. It looks like this:

```
my_func <- function(df, FUN = sum, ...) {

    < ...more stuff here ....>

    # aggregate on desired level across all columns
    df %>% group_by(level) %>% summarise_all(funs(FUN(., ...)))
}
```

The problem is, however, that *my_func* always uses the default *sum* function, even if I call it like:

```
my_func(my.data.frame, FUN="mean") # or my_func(my.data.frame, FUN=mean)
```

And passing in additional params for the *... argument* also does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One options is to use `funs_` instead of `funs`.

The function would then look like

```
my_func <- function(df, FUN = "sum", ...) {
    df %>% 
        group_by(level) %>% 
        summarise_all(funs_(FUN, args = ...))
}
```

To use the `args`, the `...` arguments would need to be put in a list.

```
my_func(datasetname, FUN="mean", list(na.rm = TRUE))
```